# frequent orientation change issue

Tags: java, exoplayer

If I am doing manual full screen for my video player with my phone in angle  with x,y,z (90,0,90) respectively, the  orientation sensor of my phone sensing it as portrait orientation and its immediately coming back to  portrait mode .can anybody guide me wt can be the solution for this .

```
@Override
public void onFullScreen(Boolean isFromButtonClick) {

    if(activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        isFullScreen = true;
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        mediaController.updateFullScreen();
        loadRecommendations();

    }
    else{
        isFullScreen = false;
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        mediaController.updateFullScreen();
    }

    if (Settings.System.getInt(activity.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }


}
```

above code is for full screen.

Comment: You may want to view https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Comment: no that is not my query . when i am changing orientation manually to landscape its going to landscape and immediately coming to portrait mode.

Comment: how to disable orientation while manual full screen

Comment: When is the `onFullScreen(...)` method called? You could switch off the auto-rotate for your app and handle it by code only, but that may become hard to do. Set `activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR)` and check out what happens.

Comment: onfullscreen(...)  is getting called when i am pressing full screen button manually. what SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR does because i tried this also nothing happened .. may be i did in wrong place .... can u tell what is the flow of this flag....

Comment: when i am clicking full screen button i am setting screen orientation to landscape manually so its going to the on-configuration change method of the activity and orientation changing to landscape but immediately its coming to portrait and i debugged it while coming to portrait mode on-configuration  is not getting called

Comment: Well, the orientation should stop listening to sensor values when set to `NOSENSOR`, but maybe that is not what makes your device auto-rotate the screen back to portrait. What's in your activity.xml? have you set a fix orientation there?

Comment: no fix orientation in activity xml..... if i will tilt my phone parallel to horizontal its not coming back to portrait....its going to landscape

Comment: Sorry, but without the full code and specific requirements I am out of ideas. Why do you make your handler set the orientation to `SENSOR` after the checks for landscape and portrait?

Comment: i dnt know what that method does it was already there i uncommented that thats it to know weather its doing something

Comment: my query is i want to disable orientation change for sometime while manual full screen click

Comment: NO_SENSOR not working in my code

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test it myself at the moment... Maybe later the day. It is possible, but I don't know how right now. Btw. it is NOSENSOR, not NO_SENSOR

Comment: yeah i know i typed it that way studio i wrote like that only..its okay no issues i will see thanks for seeking solutions ....